# How to handle "Out Of Index" exceptions in my DataSet?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

Please, help me. It's been like 3 days now I'm fighting against this thing, I'm getting completely crazy.

I got `Out Of Index Exception` in this code.
The code is used every time I push a button (from a set of 4 buttons).

My problem is every time I try to see if the row is empty, I got an exception error on my `if`.

```
//I get my dataset from my WFC from this
data = client.GetEtapes(numTransformateur, IdEtape); 

//If my dataset is empty : this is were everything blows up
if (DBNull.Value.Equals(data.Tables[0].Rows[0]))
{
    LblDateDebutEtape.Text = "Date de début d'étape : ";
    LblDateFinEtape.Text = "Date de fin d'étape : ";

    LblDateDebutEtape.Text = LblDateDebutEtape.Text + " " + data.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
    LblDateFinEtape.Text = LblDateFinEtape.Text + " " + data.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();

    LblDateDebutEtape.Visible = true;
    LblDateFinEtape.Visible = true;

    //I need to fetch another kind of data
    set = client.GetSousEtapesWithCommentary(data.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

    //Same test as before
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(set.Tables[0].Rows[0]))
    {
        Dtg_Fichiers.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
        Dtg_Fichiers.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        Dtg_Fichiers.Columns[Dtg_Fichiers.ColumnCount - 2].Visible = false;
    }
}

//In any case. Thoses does not affect the data I fetch at all.
this.GetButtonAllEnabled(button);
Dtg_Fichiers.ClearSelection();
```

I've tried so much stuff, my code is like a battlefield now.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : I'm just dumb. All I have is to go with "data.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0" in my if. Dunno why it didn't worked before. Programming logic I guess

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: Did you check the value of `data.Tables[0].Rows.Count` before accessing `data.Tables[0].Rows[0]`?

Comment: "//If my dataset is empty : this is were everything blows up

if (DBNull.Value.Equals(data.Tables[0].Rows[0]))"

Comment: Yes I did. But Even if I tried to test data.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0 or whatever the code don't give a .. and just continues to crashes

Answer (score 0):

Check for this condition in place of your if block

```
if(data.Tables.Count > 0 & data.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{ //your code
}
```

Let me know, if it solves your problem. Also share the exception.

Comment: Please explain why `?:` should be used in `if` condition.

Comment: I have added my code. However, ?: would have also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first if this is null value, because if it is you will have not 0 index.

```
if(data.Tables != null && data.Tables.Count > 0 && data.Tables[0].Rows != null && data.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{

}
```

Or you can do it smaller but not checking counts.

```
if(data.Tables != null &&  data.Tables[0].Rows != null )
{

}
```